# The dentist fixed/has fixed my tooth

Tags: verbs, phrase-choice

John chips his tooth while eating peanuts. He then goes to the dentist, and the dentist fills in the chip in his tooth. In about an hour, John, who's still having pain in his fixed tooth, bumps into Peter. Peter says to him: "You don't look very happy. What's the matter?" To which John replies with the following.

*The dentist **fixed/has fixed** my tooth. It's still giving me pain, but it'll pass shortly. I chipped it on peanuts.*

We generally use the present perfect when we tell someone something that is news to them. I wonder if in the above case John could use either tense to tell Peter about the fixed tooth. I think if he uses the present perfect "has fixed", that will mean to Peter that his tooth is now in the state "fixed." If he uses the simple past "fixed", that will mean to Peter that "John went to the dentist, and while he was there the dentist fixed his tooth." So I think that both options are appropriate in the context given.

Is my understanding correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably *wouldn't* want the perfect form. because it more strongly implies ***permanently** fixed*. But in any case, whenever you don't *need* the Perfect, you shouldn't use it. And you don't need it here. I don't know where you got the idea that *we use the present perfect when we tell someone something that is news to them*, but I don't recognize any such concept.

Comment: It would be quite idiomatic (natural) to say "*I've* just been to the dentist".

Comment: This example you give above... in ordinary conversational English, people would usually just say "fixed" instead of "has fixed." You should consider whether or not the "has" makes things clearer or not. You can say either, but "has fixed" is less common and might be considered too formal for everyday dialogue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, what do you mean by "permanently fixed"?

Comment: I mean obviously "fixed" isn't really the right word if the speaker *still* has a problem. More precisely, the dentist *attempted* (and failed) to fix things. But because the Perfect verb form implies a strong link between something in the past and the *current* state of affairs, if we're told that something ***has been fixed***, we wouldn't expect that to be followed by what effectively amounts to ***but it hasn't been fixed***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, but the tooth has been fixed. The speaker no longer has a problem with it. The remaining pain is there because anaesthesia is longer providing pain relief. That remaining pain will pass, and the fixed tooth isn't going to cause the speaker problems anymore. So the dentist didn't fail. I should've made that clear in the context. In this case, are both forms acceptable in my scenario? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's *valid* to use the Perfect form in your context. But there's no obvious reason why you *should*, so my advice remains that you shouldn't. Far more non-native speakers incorrectly *overuse* Perfect verb forms than underuse them. I guess because "the rules" look so simple people get carried away over-applying them. Native Anglophones generally favour the simplest verb forms they can get away with. (Especially when not writing essays to be marked by examiners! :)